# How can I open an existing file of excel in vba?

Tags: excel, vb.net

I want to know how can I open an existing excel file with an existing username name. e.g If the username input is `louis` and it's a new username then an excel file is created `louis.xlsx`. Then if the username is again `Louis` I want to open the same file since it already exists.

My code is the following:

```
Dim SourcePath As String = "D:\VisualStudio\JuegoDIF\" + userName + ".xlsx"
Dim SaveDirectory As String = "D:\VisualStudio\JuegoDIF\"

Dim Filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(SourcePath)
Dim SavePath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(SaveDirectory, Filename)

If System.IO.File.Exists(SavePath) Then
    'Files exists
              
    'RIGHT HERE IS WHERE I SHOULD WRITE THE IMPLEMENTATION
Else
    'File Don't Exists
    'Creating an Excel File with user information

    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object

    'Start a new workbook in Excel
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

    'Add data to cells of the first worksheet in the new workbook
    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)

    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Date"
    oSheet.Range("A2").Value = Now
    oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "Category"
    oSheet.Range("C1").Value = "correct"
    oSheet.Range("D1").Value = "answer"
    oSheet.Range("E1").Value = "Time"

    Dim usuario As String
    usuario = UserName

    'Format Cells
    oSheet.Range("A1:E1").Font.Bold = True
    'Save the Workbook and Quit
    oBook.SaveAs ("D:\VisualStudio\JuegoDIF\" + UserName + ".xlsx")
    oExcel.Quit
End If
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout I see.... yeah Vb.Net indeed

Comment: I deleted my comment above as that was for VBA. See [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/23/opening-an-excel-file/) :) Use the approach `oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open()`

Comment: @SiddharthRout thank a lot, gonna give it a try